# Python: faster normalization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, normalization, normalize

I want to normalize my ambient temperature column (Ta).
Here is my code:

```
df['Ta'] = df['Ta'].apply(lambda v: (v - df['Ta'].min())) / (df['Ta'].max() - df['Ta'].min())
```

It works well. But, it is very slow. The file size is 20 MB with the shape of (300000, 8).

Is there any other faster solution to this?

Comment: Maybe you can cache `df['Ta'].min()` and `df['Ta'].max()` in variables, instead of recomputation every time the lambda is called?

Comment: actualy you have constants : df['Ta'], (df['Ta'].max() - df['Ta'].min()), df['Ta'].min() and do not modify the content of df['Ta'] , make 
another_array = df_ta.apply...

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how to implement it. The following is correct for small data and works fast with the large data. But not sure whether it is a true solution. ```df['Ta'] = (df['Ta'] - df['Ta'].min()) / (df['Ta'].max() - df['Ta'].min())```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not take advantage of `pandas` , apply here is another layout of for loop , which will slow down the whole process

```
 import pandas as pd ; import numpy as np

 df['Ta']- df['Ta'].min() / np.ptp(df['Ta']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there would be a faster way:

```
mx = df['Ta'].max()
mn = df['Ta'].min()

df['Ta'] -=mn
df['Ta']/=(mx-mn)
```